# Big o notation $( n \log n + n \log(n^{\log n}))$

Tags: asymptotics, logarithms

I'm trying to transform this: $$n \log n + n \log(n^{\log n})$$ into big O notation.

I can't get to reduce the right part of the addition...

Neither of these work: $$n^{\log n} \log(n)\qquad\text{nor}\qquad n \log(\log n * n)$$

I was planning to get them to multiply together, and then I would have only 1 small function.

How do I reduce the right part ?

Comment: I can't quite see your formatting

Comment: thanks, I fixed the formating a bit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notice that $n\log(n^{\log n}) = n (\log n)^2$. So
$$
  n\log n + n \log(n^{\log n}) = n\log n + n \log^2 n 
$$
$$
=  n \log n(1+\log n) = n (\log n) O(\log n) = O(n \log^2 n)
$$